# FFmpeg add text in a box with rounded corners

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-encoding, ffmpeg-filters

Is there a way to add a text with countdown timer to a video using FFmpeg where the text is contained in a semi-transparent box with rounded corners with one of the side borders in a different color?

Desired output:
[image: Desired output]

Using `drawtext` filters I was able to get the box **without rounded corners** as well as the side color, but couldn't get the exact color in the output video, there seems to be discrepancy getween the hex value input and output:

Actual output:
[image: Actual output]

The command I used:

```
ffmpeg -i input_video.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile='/System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/Tahoma Bold.ttf':text='%{eif\:20-t\:d} \:דועב ליחתי ןוטרסה':box=1:boxcolor=black@0.8:boxborderw=25:fontcolor=white:fontsize=18:x=100:y=90:enable='between(t,0,5)',drawtext=fontfile='/System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/Tahoma Bold.ttf':text='|':box=1:boxcolor=#c2fd50:boxborderw=30|0|31|0:fontcolor=#c2fd50:x=333:y=95:fontsize=8:enable='between(t,0,5)'" -c:a copy output_video.mp4
```

Comment: Yes, I’ll use an image instead. Thanks. Marked it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no [`drawtext`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1) parameter for rounded corners. There are some complex workarounds like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75611512/7264739) but it's much easier to help yourself through other means.

For instance, you can abandon the `box` from it and go for [`overlay`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1) filter with an image instead:

1. Create an image for your box using any graphical tool like GIMP or ImageMagick.
2. Add it as 2nd input: `-i box.png`
3. Use mentioned `overlay` filter with the same `enable` param, similar coordinates, e.g.

```
overlay=x=100,y=90:enable='between(t,0,5)'
```

4. Make sure it's defined before `drawtext` to be layered under it.